# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [140, 70]

Tags: k-fold

I am trying to create one machine learning model using Kernel ridge regression with k-fold but I am getting the below error. Much appreciate for your informations-

```
datasetTrain = pd.read_csv('D:/set_AB.csv')
datasetTest = pd.read_csv('D:/set_C.csv')

X = datasetTrain
y = datasetTest

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
```

I am getting the following error----

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [140, 70]
```

enter code here

Answer (score 0):

**You are doing `train_test_split` that is fundamentally wrong.**

**Error**: `len(datasetTrain)=140`, `len(datasetTest)=70`. Therefore dimension mismatch.

`datasetTrain` is the dataset used for training. The train dataset in your case should contain:

`Xtrain`: The input or the predictor variables that impact the target variable .

`ytrain`: The target variable.

`datasetTest` is the dataset used for test. The test dataset in your case should contain:

`Xtest`: The input or the predictor variables that impact the target variable.

`ytest`: The target variable.

Concatenate both the `datasetTrain` and `datasetTest` along `dim=0`.

```
final_df = pd.concat([datasetTrain, datasetTest])
X = final_df["only those columns which are input variables"]
y = final_df["target_variable"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
"""
Creation of model and the training code goes here

"""
```